# SetPosition PlaceMark Yandex Map

Tags: yandex-maps-api

День добрый, мне нужно передвигать магическим образом маркеры на яндекс карте, но в документации не нашел нужной функции, да и к тому-же не могу представить как обращаться к точкам если они добавляются следующим образом:

```
var placemark = new ymaps.Placemark([55.75, 37.50], {
balloonContent: 'Маркер =)'
}, {
preset: "twirl#yellowStretchyIcon",
balloonCloseButton: true,
hideIconOnBalloonOpen: false
});
myMap.geoObjects.add(placemark);
```

Товарищи умельцы помогите пожалуйста =)

Answer (score 1):

// При клике на карте, перемещаем плейсмарк:

```
 map.events.add('click', function (e) {
        var position = e.get('coords');
        placemark.geometry.setCoordinates(position);
        });
```

А если интересует drag&drop то смотрите событие dragend